# Understanding O[]-term logic

Tags: linear-algebra, approximation

I tried to solve a linear algebraic system with a first order approximation for small parameter "d<<1". Here is a system of linear equations.

[image]

I found a true solution for it described below

[image]

Then I made an approximation using the first two members of Taylor series.
[image]

After putting it all together into the system of equations, I didn't get zero or members with variable of $d^2$ degree that I'm able to remove.

[image]

Is it right or wrong, I can't understand. But when I add O-term like this:

[image]

It finally becomes zero.

[image]

UPD:
a wolfram code for "true" solution:

```
<< Notation`
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox[Gr, i_, j_]]]
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox[k, i_]]]
kr = Sqrt[Subscript[k, 1]^2 + Subscript[k, 2]^2 + Subscript[k, 3]^2]; 
Subscript[Gr, 1, 
   1] = -((b*(Subscript[k, 2]^2 + Subscript[k, 3]^2)*
        kr^2*(a + b + d) + 
             d*Subscript[k, 2]^2*Subscript[k, 3]^2*(2*a + 2*b + d) + 
       b^2*kr^4)/
          ((2*Pi)^(3/2)*(b^2*kr^6*(a + 2*b + d) + 
         d^2*Subscript[k, 1]^2*Subscript[k, 2]^2*
          Subscript[k, 3]^2*(3*a + 3*b + d) + 

         b*d*(Subscript[k, 1]^2*Subscript[k, 2]^2 + 
            Subscript[k, 3]^2*Subscript[k, 2]^2 + 
                     Subscript[k, 1]^2*Subscript[k, 3]^2)*
          kr^2*(2*a + 2*b + d)))); 
Subscript[Gr, 2, 
   2] = -((b*(Subscript[k, 1]^2 + Subscript[k, 3]^2)*
        kr^2*(a + b + d) + 
             d*Subscript[k, 1]^2*Subscript[k, 3]^2*(2*a + 2*b + d) + 
       b^2*kr^4)/
          ((2*Pi)^(3/2)*(b^2*kr^6*(a + 2*b + d) + 
         d^2*Subscript[k, 1]^2*Subscript[k, 2]^2*
          Subscript[k, 3]^2*(3*a + 3*b + d) + 

         b*d*(Subscript[k, 1]^2*Subscript[k, 2]^2 + 
            Subscript[k, 3]^2*Subscript[k, 2]^2 + 
                     Subscript[k, 1]^2*Subscript[k, 3]^2)*
          kr^2*(2*a + 2*b + d)))); 
Subscript[Gr, 3, 
   3] = -((b*(Subscript[k, 1]^2 + Subscript[k, 2]^2)*
        kr^2*(a + b + d) + 
             d*Subscript[k, 1]^2*Subscript[k, 2]^2*(2*a + 2*b + d) + 
       b^2*kr^4)/
          ((2*Pi)^(3/2)*(b^2*kr^6*(a + 2*b + d) + 
         d^2*Subscript[k, 1]^2*Subscript[k, 2]^2*
          Subscript[k, 3]^2*(3*a + 3*b + d) + 

         b*d*(Subscript[k, 1]^2*Subscript[k, 2]^2 + 
            Subscript[k, 3]^2*Subscript[k, 2]^2 + 
                     Subscript[k, 1]^2*Subscript[k, 3]^2)*
          kr^2*(2*a + 2*b + d)))); 
Subscript[Gr, 2, 
   1] = (Subscript[k, 1]*
     Subscript[k, 2]*(a + b)*(b*kr^2 + d*Subscript[k, 3]^2))/
       ((2*Sqrt[2]*Pi^(3/2))*(b^2*kr^6*(a + 2*b + d) + 
       d^2*Subscript[k, 1]^2*Subscript[k, 2]^2*Subscript[k, 3]^2*
               (3*a + 3*b + d) + 
       b*d*(Subscript[k, 1]^2*Subscript[k, 2]^2 + 
          Subscript[k, 3]^2*Subscript[k, 2]^2 + 
                  Subscript[k, 1]^2*Subscript[k, 3]^2)*
        kr^2*(2*a + 2*b + d))); 
Subscript[Gr, 3, 
   2] = (Subscript[k, 3]*
     Subscript[k, 2]*(a + b)*(b*kr^2 + d*Subscript[k, 1]^2))/
       ((2*Sqrt[2]*Pi^(3/2))*(b^2*kr^6*(a + 2*b + d) + 
       d^2*Subscript[k, 1]^2*Subscript[k, 2]^2*Subscript[k, 3]^2*
               (3*a + 3*b + d) + 
       b*d*(Subscript[k, 1]^2*Subscript[k, 2]^2 + 
          Subscript[k, 3]^2*Subscript[k, 2]^2 + 
                  Subscript[k, 1]^2*Subscript[k, 3]^2)*
        kr^2*(2*a + 2*b + d))); 
kr = Sqrt[Subscript[k, 1]^2 + Subscript[k, 2]^2 + Subscript[k, 3]^2]; 
Simplify[{{Subscript[k, 1]^2*Subscript[Gr, 2, 1]*(a + 2*b + d) + 
     Subscript[k, 1]*(a + b)*
             (Subscript[k, 2]*Subscript[Gr, 2, 2] + 
        Subscript[k, 3]*Subscript[Gr, 3, 2]) + 

     b*(Subscript[k, 2]^2 + Subscript[k, 3]^2)*Subscript[Gr, 2, 1] == 
    0}, 
     {4*Pi^(3/
         2)*(Subscript[Gr, 2, 
          2]*(Subscript[k, 2]^2*(a + 2*b + d) + b*Subscript[k, 3]^2) + 

        Subscript[k, 2]*Subscript[k, 1]*Subscript[Gr, 2, 1]*(a + b) + 
        Subscript[k, 2]*Subscript[k, 3]*
                  Subscript[Gr, 3, 2]*(a + b) + 
        b*Subscript[k, 1]^2*Subscript[Gr, 2, 2]) + Sqrt[2] == 0}, 
     {Subscript[Gr, 3, 
       2]*(Subscript[k, 3]^2*(a + 2*b + d) + 
        b*(Subscript[k, 1]^2 + Subscript[k, 2]^2)) + 

     Subscript[k, 
       3]*(a + b)*(Subscript[k, 1]*Subscript[Gr, 2, 1] + 
        Subscript[k, 2]*Subscript[Gr, 2, 2]) == 0}}]
```

I know, its unreadable, but if you convert it to traditional form it will become normal. Then, I got

```
{{True}, {True}, {True}}
```

Let me use an approximated solution.

```
kr = Sqrt[Subscript[k, 1]^2 + Subscript[k, 2]^2 + Subscript[k, 3]^2]; 
Subscript[Gur, 2, 
   2] = ((-(a + 2*b))*Subscript[k, 1]^2 - 
      b*Subscript[k, 2]^2 - (a + 2*b)*Subscript[k, 3]^2)/
         (2*Sqrt[2]*b*(a + 2*b)*
      Pi^(3/2)*(Subscript[k, 1]^2 + Subscript[k, 2]^2 + 
         Subscript[k, 3]^2)^2) + 
       d*((Subscript[k, 
          2]^2*((2*a^2 + 6*a*b + 5*b^2)*Subscript[k, 1]^4 + 
          b^2*Subscript[k, 2]^4 + 
          2*b*(a + 2*b)*Subscript[k, 2]^2*Subscript[k, 3]^2 + 
                  (2*a^2 + 6*a*b + 5*b^2)*Subscript[k, 3]^4 + 
          2*(a + 2*b)*
           Subscript[k, 
             1]^2*(b*Subscript[k, 2]^2 + (a + 2*b)*
              Subscript[k, 3]^2)))/
            (2*Sqrt[2]*b^2*(a + 2*b)^2*
        Pi^(3/2)*(Subscript[k, 1]^2 + Subscript[k, 2]^2 + 
           Subscript[k, 3]^2)^4)); 
Subscript[Gur, 2, 
   1] = ((a + b)*Subscript[k, 1]*Subscript[k, 2])/(2*Sqrt[2]*
      b*(a + 2*b)*Pi^(3/2)*
            (Subscript[k, 1]^2 + Subscript[k, 2]^2 + 
         Subscript[k, 3]^2)^2) - 
       d*(((a + b)*Subscript[k, 1]*
        Subscript[k, 
         2]*(b*Subscript[k, 1]^4 + 
          b*Subscript[k, 2]^4 + (a + 2*b)*Subscript[k, 2]^2*
           Subscript[k, 3]^2 - 
                  (a + b)*Subscript[k, 3]^4 + (a + 2*b)*
           Subscript[k, 1]^2*(2*Subscript[k, 2]^2 + 
             Subscript[k, 3]^2)))/
            (2*Sqrt[2]*b^2*(a + 2*b)^2*
        Pi^(3/2)*(Subscript[k, 1]^2 + Subscript[k, 2]^2 + 
           Subscript[k, 3]^2)^4)); 
Subscript[Gur, 3, 
   2] = ((a + b)*Subscript[k, 2]*Subscript[k, 3])/(2*Sqrt[2]*
      b*(a + 2*b)*Pi^(3/2)*
            (Subscript[k, 1]^2 + Subscript[k, 2]^2 + 
         Subscript[k, 3]^2)^2) - 
       d*(((a + b)*Subscript[k, 2]*
        Subscript[k, 
         3]*((-(a + b))*Subscript[k, 1]^4 + b*Subscript[k, 2]^4 + 
          2*(a + 2*b)*Subscript[k, 2]^2*Subscript[k, 3]^2 + 

          b*Subscript[k, 3]^4 + (a + 2*b)*
           Subscript[k, 1]^2*(Subscript[k, 2]^2 + 
             Subscript[k, 3]^2)))/(2*Sqrt[2]*b^2*(a + 2*b)^2*Pi^(3/2)*
               (Subscript[k, 1]^2 + Subscript[k, 2]^2 + 
           Subscript[k, 3]^2)^4)); 
Simplify[{{(a + 2*b + d)*Subscript[k, 1]^2*Subscript[Gur, 2, 1] + 
     b*(Subscript[k, 2]^2 + Subscript[k, 3]^2)*Subscript[Gur, 2, 1] + 
           (a + b)*
      Subscript[k, 
       1]*(Subscript[k, 2]*Subscript[Gur, 2, 2] + 
        Subscript[k, 3]*Subscript[Gur, 3, 2]) == 0}, 
     {Sqrt[2] + 
     4*Pi^(3/2)*((a + b)*Subscript[k, 1]*Subscript[k, 2]*
         Subscript[Gur, 2, 1] + 
        b*Subscript[k, 1]^2*Subscript[Gur, 2, 2] + 
                ((a + 2*b + d)*Subscript[k, 2]^2 + 
           b*Subscript[k, 3]^2)*Subscript[Gur, 2, 2] + (a + b)*
         Subscript[k, 2]*Subscript[k, 3]*Subscript[Gur, 3, 2]) == 
         0}, {(a + b)*
      Subscript[k, 
       3]*(Subscript[k, 1]*Subscript[Gur, 2, 1] + 
        Subscript[k, 2]*Subscript[Gur, 2, 2]) + 
           (b*(Subscript[k, 1]^2 + Subscript[k, 2]^2) + (a + 2*b + d)*
         Subscript[k, 3]^2)*Subscript[Gur, 3, 2] == 0}}]
```

It doesn't lead to zero. But when I add O-term to each function "Gur":

```
kr = Sqrt[Subscript[k, 1]^2 + Subscript[k, 2]^2 + Subscript[k, 3]^2]; 
Subscript[Gur, 2, 
   2] = ((-(a + 2*b))*Subscript[k, 1]^2 - 
      b*Subscript[k, 2]^2 - (a + 2*b)*Subscript[k, 3]^2)/
         (2*Sqrt[2]*b*(a + 2*b)*
      Pi^(3/2)*(Subscript[k, 1]^2 + Subscript[k, 2]^2 + 
         Subscript[k, 3]^2)^2) + 
       d*((Subscript[k, 
          2]^2*((2*a^2 + 6*a*b + 5*b^2)*Subscript[k, 1]^4 + 
          b^2*Subscript[k, 2]^4 + 
          2*b*(a + 2*b)*Subscript[k, 2]^2*Subscript[k, 3]^2 + 
                  (2*a^2 + 6*a*b + 5*b^2)*Subscript[k, 3]^4 + 
          2*(a + 2*b)*
           Subscript[k, 
             1]^2*(b*Subscript[k, 2]^2 + (a + 2*b)*
              Subscript[k, 3]^2)))/
            (2*Sqrt[2]*b^2*(a + 2*b)^2*
        Pi^(3/2)*(Subscript[k, 1]^2 + Subscript[k, 2]^2 + 
           Subscript[k, 3]^2)^4)) + SeriesData[d, 0, {}, 2, 2, 1]; 
Subscript[Gur, 2, 
   1] = ((a + b)*Subscript[k, 1]*Subscript[k, 2])/(2*Sqrt[2]*
      b*(a + 2*b)*Pi^(3/2)*
            (Subscript[k, 1]^2 + Subscript[k, 2]^2 + 
         Subscript[k, 3]^2)^2) - 
       d*(((a + b)*Subscript[k, 1]*
        Subscript[k, 
         2]*(b*Subscript[k, 1]^4 + 

          b*Subscript[k, 2]^4 + (a + 2*b)*Subscript[k, 2]^2*
           Subscript[k, 3]^2 - 
                  (a + b)*Subscript[k, 3]^4 + (a + 2*b)*
           Subscript[k, 1]^2*(2*Subscript[k, 2]^2 + 
             Subscript[k, 3]^2)))/
            (2*Sqrt[2]*b^2*(a + 2*b)^2*
        Pi^(3/2)*(Subscript[k, 1]^2 + Subscript[k, 2]^2 + 
           Subscript[k, 3]^2)^4)) + SeriesData[d, 0, {}, 2, 2, 1]; 
Subscript[Gur, 3, 
   2] = ((a + b)*Subscript[k, 2]*Subscript[k, 3])/(2*Sqrt[2]*
      b*(a + 2*b)*Pi^(3/2)*
            (Subscript[k, 1]^2 + Subscript[k, 2]^2 + 
         Subscript[k, 3]^2)^2) - 
       d*(((a + b)*Subscript[k, 2]*
        Subscript[k, 
         3]*((-(a + b))*Subscript[k, 1]^4 + b*Subscript[k, 2]^4 + 
          2*(a + 2*b)*Subscript[k, 2]^2*Subscript[k, 3]^2 + 

          b*Subscript[k, 3]^4 + (a + 2*b)*
           Subscript[k, 1]^2*(Subscript[k, 2]^2 + 
             Subscript[k, 3]^2)))/(2*Sqrt[2]*b^2*(a + 2*b)^2*Pi^(3/2)*
               (Subscript[k, 1]^2 + Subscript[k, 2]^2 + 
           Subscript[k, 3]^2)^4)) + SeriesData[d, 0, {}, 2, 2, 1]; 
Simplify[{{(a + 2*b + d)*Subscript[k, 1]^2*Subscript[Gur, 2, 1] + 
     b*(Subscript[k, 2]^2 + Subscript[k, 3]^2)*Subscript[Gur, 2, 1] + 
           (a + b)*
      Subscript[k, 
       1]*(Subscript[k, 2]*Subscript[Gur, 2, 2] + 
        Subscript[k, 3]*Subscript[Gur, 3, 2]) == 0}, 
     {Sqrt[2] + 
     4*Pi^(3/2)*((a + b)*Subscript[k, 1]*Subscript[k, 2]*
         Subscript[Gur, 2, 1] + 
        b*Subscript[k, 1]^2*Subscript[Gur, 2, 2] + 
                ((a + 2*b + d)*Subscript[k, 2]^2 + 
           b*Subscript[k, 3]^2)*Subscript[Gur, 2, 2] + (a + b)*
         Subscript[k, 2]*Subscript[k, 3]*Subscript[Gur, 3, 2]) == 
         0}, {(a + b)*
      Subscript[k, 
       3]*(Subscript[k, 1]*Subscript[Gur, 2, 1] + 
        Subscript[k, 2]*Subscript[Gur, 2, 2]) + 
           (b*(Subscript[k, 1]^2 + Subscript[k, 2]^2) + (a + 2*b + d)*
         Subscript[k, 3]^2)*Subscript[Gur, 3, 2] == 0}}]
```

It becomes:

```
{{SeriesData[d, 0, {}, 2, 2, 1] == 0}, {SeriesData[
   d, 0, {}, 2, 2, 1] == 0}, {SeriesData[d, 0, {}, 2, 2, 1] == 0}}
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you posted the code that led to your results so that it can be copied and analyzed. Images of long formulas are less helpful.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated this post.

Comment: Ok, @henrik-schumacher. I have simplified the example  `x := 1/a^2 - (2 c)/a^3 + SeriesData[c, 0, {}, 2, 2, 1];   y := 
 1/a^2 - (2 c)/a^3;   (a + c)^2 x == 1 // Simplify   
  (a + c)^2 y == 1 // Simplify `  In the second case it gives zero plus O-term.

Comment: Codewise this would be far more legible if the `Symbolize` stuff were avoided and e.g. `k[1]` was used instead of the subscripted form.

Answer (score 1):

I finnaly realised that mathematica actually keeps the degree of constants (it is "d" in my case) on 1 in expressions which are being compared with zero.

```
in[0]: xy(a+b)d*d == 0 //Simplify

out[0]: xy(a+b)d == 0
```